# YouTube API: orderby causes deleted videos in results?

Tags: youtube-api

I have uploaded 1 video to my YouTube channel. Everything works fine when I try to get the list of uploaded videos this way:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/[*my user name*]/uploads
```

But when I try to sort it, I get a list of 2 deleted videos that I am assuming were uploaded during one of my earlier tests:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/[*my user name*]/uploads?orderby=published
```

Any ideas what might be going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including orderby= causes requests to go against the search index rather than the backend datastore:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_feeds#User_Uploaded_Videos